# Нарисовать иконку поверх другой в QToolButton Qt5

Tags: c++, qt

Есть QToolButton ей в таблице стилей .qss задется border-image:

```
border-image: url(:/Images/image.png) 0 0 0 0 stretch stretch;
```

При клике на эту кнопку на ней должна прорисовываться другая картинка меньшего размера в виде галочки.

Как реализовать прорисовку одной картинки поверх другой?

Я понимаю, что это делается в paintEvent, но у меня вот такая штука что-то не отрабатывается:

```
QWidget::paintEvent(event);
    if (m_toolButton->isChecked())
    {
        const QPixmap overlay(":/Images/image.png");
        QPainter painter(m_toolButton);
        painter.drawPixmap(m_toolButton->width(), m_toolButton->height(), overlay);
    }
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что так не получится -- чтобы на виджете нарисовать обычно наследуются от него и в его событии paintEvent на нем рисуют. Добавьте весь код. Кст, а почему бы QPainter'ом не нарисовать на иконку у той кнопки. А после эту новую иконку установить кнопке?

Comment: Ну да, придется наследоваться от QToolButton. Думал может проще как то сделать. В стилях разрулить

Comment: Попроще будет: рисовать не на виджете, а на картинке. Или сразу заготовьте картинки и меняйте иконку кнопки при каких-то событиях. Возможно и стили помогут -- они же css-подобные, а там такое можно